# Scrolling Marquee Text cuts out on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm having a problem with my code for mobile that keeps cutting out once it reaches the end of the screen to the opposite direction of the scrolling (left).

I'm using Wix (unfortunately) where code needs to be loaded via a widget from an URL. I've got that sorted though- so that shouldn't be the issue. I'm rather thinking it is the code because it works flawlessly on desktop.

The max pixel width I can use- or rather, should use is 325 px, hence the width.

CSS below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'akira';
    src: url('./assets/142-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./assets/142-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .marquee {
    width: 325;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .marquee div {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'akira';
    padding-left: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate {
    100% {
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
  }
```

HTML HERE

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <div class="marquee">
        <div>As of current, Ytems®, is a non-profit organization.
             We sell our products at a breakeven profit. 
             Enjoy designer apparel for minimum costs. </div>
      </div>      
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by 'cutting out' - I can't see a problem on various mobile emulator settings.

Comment: Thank you for responding, This is how it looks in mobile; https://imgur.com/a/s4ravo8

Answer (score 1):

Change the marquee width to 100% or 325px depending on your needs. There are 2 snippets below - one at 100% and the other at 325px. See the comment in `.marquee`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'akira';
  src: url('./assets/142-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/142-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.marquee {
  width: 100%;  /*--------------------- changed from 325 (invalid) to 100%*/
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee div {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'akira';
  padding-left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<div class="marquee">
  <div>As of current, Ytems®, is a non-profit organization. We sell our products at a breakeven profit. Enjoy designer apparel for minimum costs. </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I see that you mention in your question that you want it to be 325px wide. Your setting of `width: 325` is invalid. I changed it to `width: 325px` in the snippet below:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'akira';
  src: url('./assets/142-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./assets/142-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.marquee {
  width: 325px;  /*--------------------- changed from 325 (invalid) to 325px */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee div {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'akira';
  padding-left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<div class="marquee">
  <div>As of current, Ytems®, is a non-profit organization. We sell our products at a breakeven profit. Enjoy designer apparel for minimum costs. </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your answer- I originally used 100% so I tried changing it to 325. Changed it back to 100%, but no luck. Here’s how it looks on mobile; https://imgur.com/a/s4ravo8

Comment: @AnthonWansland - Make sure you try '325px'. Don't forget the 'px'.

Comment: Tried, no luck. Strange. I'm testing different widget dimensions to see if it works that way instead. Highly appreciate your help though!

Comment: That is strange behavior in the video you show. Maybe device specific. When I emulate a mobile device in the Chrome dev tools it works well using 325px.